# Jasmine Testing Angular Controller Method

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

So I have my blank tests passing with this setup.

```
describe('loginController', function() {
  var scope, createController;

  beforeEach(module('souply'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$location_) {
    $location = _$location_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('loginController', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    };
  }));
```

And here are the tests...

```
describe('processGoogleLogin', function(){
describe('successful', function(){
  beforeEach(function() {

  });

  it('should connect to google plus', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
```

This one passes no problem.

**QUESTION: How can I test a method on the login controller?**

Here is the method I want to test on the login controller:

```
 $scope.processGoogleLogin = function(){
    console.log('process login was clicked');
    window.location.replace('/#/dashboard');
  };
```

The test I have so far is:

```
it('should sign you into the dashboard', function () {
    scope.processGoogleLogin();
    //$controller.processGoogleLogin();
    //expect(window.location).toBe('/#/dashboard');
  });
```

This test throws an error of:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'scope.processGoogleLogin()')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needed this line.

```
var ctrl = $controllerConstructor('myController', {$scope: scope, myResolve: {}, state: state});
```